# Finding escape characters in AT&T x86 assembly

Tags: string, gcc, assembly, character, match

**Question 1:** I have the following assembler code, whose purpose is to loop through an input string, and count the number of escape characters '%' it encounters:

```
.globl sprinter

.data

.escape_string: .string "%"

.num_escape: .long 0

.num_characters: .long 0

.text

sprinter:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp

    movl 8(%ebp),%ecx # %ecx = parameter 1

loop:
    cmpb $0, (%ecx) # if end of string reached
    jz exit
    cmpl $.escape_string,(%ecx) # if escape character found
    je increment
    back:
        incl .num_characters
        incl %ecx
        jmp loop

increment:
    incl .num_escape
    jmp back # jump to 'back'

exit:
    movl .num_escape, %eax # return num_escape

    popl %ebp
    ret
```

This assembly code is compiled together with the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int sprinter (char* string);
int main (void)
{
    int n = sprinter("a %d string of some %s fashion!");
    printf("value: %d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output from running this code is `value: 2` (because there are two '%' characters in the string), but it returns `value: 0`, meaning the following line fails (because it never increments the counter):

```
cmpl $.escape_string,(%ecx) # if escape character found
```

Am I using the wrong method of comparing for the string? The outer loop works fine, and .num_characters correctly contains the number of characters in my string. I generated some assembly code for a simple C-program that compared a string "hello" to "hello2", and this is the relevant code:

```
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
.LC1:
    .string "hello2"

...
movl    $.LC0, -4(%ebp)
cmpl    $.LC1, -4(%ebp)
```

It looks very similar to what I tried, no?

**Question 2**. This code is part of what is going to be a simplified sprintf-function written in assembly. This means the first parameter should be the result string, and the second parameter is the formatting. How do I copy a byte character from our current position in one register to our current position in another register? Let's assume we've assigned our parameters into two registers:

```
movl 8(%ebp),%edx # %edx = result-string
movl 12(%ebp),%ecx # %ecx = format-string
```

I tried the following in the loop:

```
movb (%ecx), %al
movb %al, (%edx) # copy current character to current position in result register
incl %ecx
incl %edx
```

But the result string just contains `a` (the first character in my string), and not the full string as I expected.

All help appreciated because this comparison problem (question 1) is currently keeping me stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to question 1, it appears that you are comparing single byte chars so 'cmpl' should be 'cmpb' when checking for the escape character. You will also need to load your character into a register. I'm not really familiar with AT&T assembly, so I hope this is correct.

Before loop:

```
movb .escape_string, %al
```

Comparison:

```
cmpb %al, %(ecx)
```

Comment: This returns: `/tmp/ccZauarM.o: In function 'loop':
(.text+0xd): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against '.data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` which led me to believe that the string is actually stored as a long and it was truncating the string for it to fit into the byte comparion, is this a wrong interpretation of the error?

Comment: I believe .escape_string refers to the address of the literal string. You will need to load your character into a byte register.

Comment: Moving it into a byte register and then comparing worked well! Thank you!

Comment: Cool. I'm not really sure the code I put in the answer is syntactically correct for AT&T. You may want to make an edit if it is off.

Comment: Your first edit was correct and worked for me, i.e. `movb .escape_string, %al`, I can't edit it since it's less than 6 characters edited.

Comment: Can I set multiple answers as accepted? I can accept this as the answer of question 1, but question 2 is unanswered (I've revised the second question).

Comment: Can you post the full loop?

Comment: I figured it out. The code actually worked, I had just misplaced the copy in relation to a jump sequence. Thank you very much!